# How would I fix my list query (Bigquery SQL)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to make a query that lists players underneath the college they played for before joining the NFL. I'd like to remove the null values and only list players under each school. Do you guys know how I could do this? I've tried writing an "is null" statement and making it into a cte with no luck. Any input is appreciated. Here is my code:

```
Select * from(
Select 
collegeName, displayName,ANY_VALUE(displayName) as Player
from NFL.Players
group by collegeName,displayName)
Pivot (Any_Value(Player) for collegeName in('Kansas State','Abilene Christian','Texas Tech'))
```

Comment: When you group by collegeName,displayName you get a row for each unique combination of values from those columns. So unless you have duplicate names from the same college, every "any_value(displayname)" will simply be equal to  the displayname. Supply `sample data` and `expected result` (derived from only the sample data). Do not use images for either, provide text tables.

Comment: *How would I fix my query* is not a meaningful title. Please [edit] it to describe the actual problem you're having. The title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user skimming a list of search results will know what it's about. The title now says absolutely nothing meaningful. For help in writing a good title, see [ask]. You may also want to read [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use a `PIVOT` with the `STRING_AGG` aggregate function.

```
WITH
  players AS (
    SELECT "Kansas State" AS collegeName, "Player 1" AS displayName
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "Abilene Christian" AS collegeName, "Player 2" AS displayName
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "Kansas State" AS collegeName, "Player 3" AS displayName
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "Texas Tech" AS collegeName, "Player 4" AS displayName
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "Kansas State" AS collegeName, "Player 5" AS displayName
  )

SELECT 
  *
FROM players
PIVOT(STRING_AGG(displayName) FOR collegeName IN ('Kansas State', 'Abilene Christian', 'Texas Tech'))
```

This will result in :

```
+----------------------------+-------------------+------------+
| Kansas State               | Abilene Christian | Texas Tech |
+----------------------------+-------------------+------------+
| Player 1,Player 3,Player 5 | Player 2          | Player 4   |
+----------------------------+-------------------+------------+
```